# critical regions, power functions in statistics

Tags: statistics

[image]

for the first part I identified the critical region as C={${(x_1,...,x_n)}= \bar{x} > 63.3$}. I'm not really sure how to find the power using this. I tried:

Power=P(reject $H_0$| $H_0$ is false)
=P($\bar x > 63.3| \mu >60$)

but then I get stuck. I'm not sure how to pivot here (if I can?).

And then we've never talked about power functions in lecture, and the text book was very vague on the subject. If someone could enlighten me, that would be terrific.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that the alternative hypothesis is not simple, i.e., it's not a single point in parameter space. You have a composite hypothesis, namely the interval $(60, \infty)$. So the power of the test is actually a function of $\mu$ in this interval. I'll try to explain in more detail:

The expression $P(\bar{x}>63.3|\mu>60)$ does NOT make sense. Your $\mu$ is not a random variable, it's a parameter. Although the error probabilities of types I and II are often written as a conditional probability, as in $P(reject\, H_0|H_0\, is\, false)$, that's NOT what they mean. The condition $H_0 is false$ is not random, there is no probability distribution saying what values of $\mu$ are more or less likely to occur.

Rejecting or accepting $H_0$, on the other hand, is a random event, because the sample is random, and there is a probability distribution telling how likely it is for the statistic $\bar{x}$ to be found inside or outside the critical region.

Now here is the catch: the probability distribution mentioned in the paragraph above, also known as the sampling distribution of $\bar{x}$, *depends* on the parameter $\mu$. When you calculated the critical region to match the significance level, you used $\mu=60$ to specify this distribution.

To find the power, you have to calculate $P(reject\, H_0)=P(\bar{x}>63.3)$ taking into account that the distribution of $\bar{x}$ contains an unknown parameter, $\mu$. The resulting expression is your power function for $\mu > 60$.

Honestly, I'd say item (b) of your workbook is badly stated. Can you work out itens (c) and (d) now?